# Check if JSON's response is empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am getting some data from MySQL through JSON.  However I want to target whether the response is empty or not, so that if it is not empty I show the info returned, otherwise I show a message.

I have tried multiple possible solutions like checking the length of the JSON response, check if item Severity is there and if not assume it is null etc.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/php/loaddata.php?&jsoncallback=?',
    dataType: 'JSONp',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.Severity == 1) {   
                // Do Something
                .....
```

When JSON finds data, the reply is something like this:
**UPDATED:**

```
([{"Severity":"1","Latitude":"35.872883","Longitude":"14.449133","Address":"Some Address 1","Heading":"25","Timestamp":"2012-12-28 10:15:03"},{"Severity":"2","Latitude":"35.871269","Longitude":"14.501580","Address":"Some Address 2","Heading":"80","Timestamp":"2012-12-28 10:15:31"}]);
```

Else if no data is found, JSON returns:

```
([]);
```

Comment: Did you check on data.length ?

Comment: @ryadavilli  Yes however it did not work.

I tried 
if (data.length === 0)

Comment: You need to negate that expression

Comment: So, if the data is empty, what ___exactly___ is returned? (`console.log(typeof data, data);`)

Comment: That's wierd. If you get an empty array, data will actually be an array with length 0.

Comment: Please, not this approach! ;)

Comment: Sounds like a json parsing problem. I'd try adding `$.parseJSON`

Comment: @Bhavin: at least "==" or "===" not "=", I gave an answer using casting to string (which works most of the time for this) but as it was quickly downvoted I guess that is not what you were looking for (I deleted it). Also a little remark: it is safer sending an object containing your array than your array directly (some tools considers a json must starts with an object and therefore does not parse them correctly)

Comment: @Dabido: That just uses `JSON.parse` under the hood.

Comment: @Cerbrus  Console.log returned "string"

Comment: Not sure what jQuery is doing but `([])` doesn't seem to be valid. I might be wrong because of JSONP though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since: *Console.log returned `"string"` – [user1809790](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067580/check-if-jsons-response-is-empty#comment19445965_14067580)*,
this should work:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data != '' && data !== null) { // Check if the data's not an empty string or null.
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.Severity == 1) {
                // Do Something
```

Comment: I would add `&& data !== null` to this solution. When jQuery tries to parse a string that is not json, it will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a casting will let the js engine do the parsing job:

```
if (""+data == "")
{
alert("Data is empty");
}
```

Note: only an empty string or an empty array (which could recursively contains other empty strings / arrays) will make this condition be satisfied, which fits your requirement

Comment: Ok I undeleted my answer, If you think this will not work, please explain why.

Comment: Hm, I think casting the data to string is a pretty ugly way to check if it's empty, especially since the data (response) is a string, already.

Comment: I do not think so, otherwise the question is inaccurate: data = [{"key":"val"}]; And not data = "[{\"key\":\"val\"}]"; which is absolutely not the same.

Comment: A (json) result from php is always a string. (Unless you're returning images and the like)

Comment: Ok this is related to the dataType, now specifying dataType to "json" will make jQuery parse it for you (and returning the parsed object). Now I assumed "JSONp" to act the same way as "json" which should be the case according to the doc (but never tried): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

data you'll get on success is JSON , so firstly you have to parse it ,so this will do for you

```
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data) // this will give you array 
if(x.length == 0) {
    alert("empty");
}
```

Comment: @sourecode I tried this but it gave me an error:
Uncaught TypeError:  Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: use this A.splice(0, A.length) , and also you can also use stringyfy() that will give you emty string , then you can check for empty one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the expression is negated.

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.length != 0){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            if (item.Severity == 1) {
                //Do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet

```
var result="[]"; // this is your json string result
var parsed=jQuery.parseJSON(result); //this is now an array! so we can check the length

if(parsed.length==0)
    alert("Error")
```

Comment: This will not work if the JSON result is an Object. Objects don't have the `.length` property. (JSON responses are more often than not Objects)

Comment: in both examples he posted, there were arrays, not objects, so I assumed we were working with just arrays

Comment: @LucaTrazzi  in my case, where would I need to put this code?  Under the success function?  (sorry - I am a n00b in this :( )

Comment: yea, but result is your data :)

Answer (score 0):

`([])` is not valid json and therefore can't be parsed. `[]` is.

This will throw a syntax error:

```
var json = "([])";
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.length);
```

While this is working and will output 0:

```
var json = "[]";
var obj JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.length);
```

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/m9LUm/1/